# centering tables

Tags: tables

I am trying to create my CV, using tables. I want them in the center of the page, but they continue to position a little bit to the left. I am using the command `\centering` before the environment `tabular`. I think I understood the reason, that is the text on the first column is not long enough, in the second table. How can I solve this?

[image]

The first table is centered, but the second, as you can noticed, is not.

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, Arial]{article}

\usepackage{float} % force LaTex to not reposition the tables
\usepackage{xcolor} % used to change the colour of the author
\usepackage{hyperref} % to use links 

% BEGINNING OF THE DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
%
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
%
\maketitle
%
\subsection*{Personal Information}
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{25pt}
        \begin{tabular}{ r | l}
            \textbf{Name and surname} & Barack \\
            \textbf{Address} & Washington\\     
            &USA\\
            \textbf{Number} & +1231231231231 \\
            \textbf{E-mail addresses} & barack@obama.usa \\
            \textbf{Nationality} & American \\
            \textbf{Birth} & 28/10/1923 \\
            \textbf{Gender} & Male \\
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
%
%
\subsection*{Education}
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{25pt}
        \begin{tabular}{ r | l}
            \textbf{University} & \textcolor{blue}{\href{https://www.google.com}{google}} \\
            \textbf{Faculty} & Science of Informatics\\
            \textbf{Date} & 1900 - present \\   
            \textbf{Country} & Earth \\
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The *table* probably *is* centred. Do you want the vertical lines in the middle to align? If so, specify the column widths with something like `p@{.5\linewidth}` rather than `r` and `l`.

Comment: It's not a "problem" it's just a natural feature of centering that if you add text, the table moves. The second table is centred. It may be that you don't want that layout, but that's a different thing.

Comment: You do not need or want `\begin{table}[H]` here, just don't use `\begin{table}` at all, you don't want a float, just a cemtred tabular.

Comment: What does "stupid manager" in the title mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want cells as wide as half the text width, but to also subtract the intercolumn padding and the rule width.

It's also better to define an environment, rather than repeating over and over the same input.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array,calc,xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  urlcolor=blue,
}

\newenvironment{data}
 {\par\centering
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{25pt}%
  \begin{tabular}{
    @{}% no padding at the left
    >{\raggedleft\bfseries}p{.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep-.5\arrayrulewidth}% right aligned column
    |% separator
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep-.5\arrayrulewidth}% left aligned column
    @{}% no padding at the right
  }}
  {\end{tabular}\par}

\linespread{1.3}

\begin{document}
  %
  %
  % \maketitle
  %
\subsection*{Personal Information}

\begin{data}
Name and surname & Barack \\
Address          & Washington\newline USA \\
Number           & +1231231231231 \\
E-mail addresses & \texttt{barack@obama.usa} \\
Nationality      & American \\
Birth            & 28/10/1923 \\
Gender           & Male \\
\end{data}

\subsection*{Education}

\begin{data}
University & \href{https://www.google.com}{google} \\
Faculty    & Science of Informatics\\
Date       & 1900 -- present \\
Country    & Earth \\
\end{data}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Do you want something like this?

[image: aligned vertical rules]

```
\documentclass[12pt, Arial]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float} % force LaTex to not reposition the tables
\usepackage{xcolor} % used to change the colour of the author
\usepackage{hyperref} % to use links

% BEGINNING OF THE DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
  %
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
  %
  % \maketitle
  %
  \subsection*{Personal Information}

  {\centering
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{25pt}
    \begin{tabular}{ >{\raggedleft}p{.5\linewidth} | p{.5\linewidth} }
      \textbf{Name and surname} & Barack \\
      \textbf{Address} & Washington\\
      &USA\\
      \textbf{Number} & +1231231231231 \\
      \textbf{E-mail addresses} & barack@obama.usa \\
      \textbf{Nationality} & American \\
      \textbf{Birth} & 28/10/1923 \\
      \textbf{Gender} & Male \\
    \end{tabular}}
  %
  %
  \subsection*{Education}

  {\centering
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{25pt}
    \begin{tabular}{ >{\raggedleft}p{.5\linewidth} | p{.5\linewidth} }
      \textbf{University} & \textcolor{blue}{\href{https://www.google.com}{google}} \\
      \textbf{Faculty} & Science of Informatics\\
      \textbf{Date} & 1900 - present \\
      \textbf{Country} & Earth \\
    \end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution with the `tabularx` package. It doesn't have to be centred since its total width is equal to \linewidth, and doesn't require the `table` environment since you do not want it to float. I managed to use `Arial` with the `winfonts` package (to install oneself: it is not part of TeX Live nor MiKTeX. Actually, it would be simpler to use it `directly` with Xe/LuaLaTeX and the `fontspec` package.

It is not recommended to change `\baselinestretch` as it has unwanted side effects. I replaced it with the `setspace` package, wich cater for  those side effects, and the `onehalfspacing` switch.

```
    \documentclass[12pt, Arial]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage[x11names]{xcolor} % used to change the colour of the author
    \usepackage{tabularx, colortbl}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{winfonts}
    \renewcommand\sfdefault{arial}

    \usepackage{hyperref} % to use links
    % BEGINNING OF THE DOCUMENT
    \begin{document}
    \sffamily
    \onehalfspacing
    %\maketitle
    %
    \subsection*{Personal Information}
    \medskip
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{25pt}
    \arrayrulecolor{Turquoise1!50!}\setlength\arrayrulewidth{.8pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\raggedleft}X | X}
    \textbf{Name and surname} & Barack \\
    \textbf{Address} & Washington\\
    &USA\\
    \textbf{Number} & +1231231231231 \\
    \textbf{E-mail addresses} & barack@obama.usa \\
    \textbf{Nationality} & American \\
    \textbf{Birth} & 28/10/1923 \\
    \textbf{Gender} & Male \\
    \end{tabularx}

    \subsection*{Education}
    \medskip
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\raggedleft}X |X}
    \textbf{University} & \textcolor{blue}{\href{https://www.google.com}{google}} \\
    \textbf{Faculty} & Science of Informatics\\
    \textbf{Date} & 1900 - present \\
    \textbf{Country} & Earth \\
    \end{tabularx}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One solution using the package [`tabu`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tabu/tabu.pdf).

```
\documentclass[12pt, Arial]{article}

\usepackage{float} % force LaTex to not reposition the tables
\usepackage{xcolor} % used to change the colour of the author
\usepackage{hyperref} % to use links 
\usepackage{tabu}

% BEGINNING OF THE DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
%
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}

\subsection*{Personal Information}
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{25pt}
        \begin{tabu}{>{\bfseries} X[r] | X[l]}
            Name and surname & Barack \\
            Address & Washington\\     
            &USA\\
            Number & +1231231231231 \\
            E-mail addresses & barack@obama.usa \\
            Nationality & American \\
            Birth & 28/10/1923 \\
            Gender & Male \\
        \end{tabu}
\end{table}
%
%
\subsection*{Education}
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{25pt}
        \begin{tabu}{>{\bfseries} X[r]|X[l]}
            University & \textcolor{blue}{\href{https://www.google.com}{google}} \\
            Faculty & Science of Informatics\\
            Date & 1900 - present \\   
            Country & Earth \\
        \end{tabu}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```