# How to center align a table with lots of columns in LaTeX?

Tags: tables

So I have a table with lots of columns. Because of this there's a lot of space on the left (i.e. `\parindent`) and very little space on the right of the table:

[image: Too much space on the right]

Here's the relevant code:

```
{\scriptsize\begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | c | c | c | c | c | c | }
\hline
\textbf{Term} & \textbf{Subject} & \textbf{Subject Name} & \textbf{Max} & \textbf{Min} & \textbf{Marks} & \textbf{Credits} & \textbf{Passed in} & \textbf{Remark} \\
~ & \textbf{Code} & ~ & \textbf{Marks} & \textbf{Marks} & \textbf{Obtained} & ~ & \textbf{Exam} & ~ \\ \hline
I. & IT-41 & Mathematics-I & 100 & 40 & 69 & 4 & Dec, 2009 & ~ \\ \hline
I. & IT-2 & Communication Skill & 100 & 40 & 62 & 3 & Dec, 2009 & ~ \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{I.} & \multirow{2}{*}{IT-4} & Electronic Devices and & \multirow{2}{*}{200} & \multirow{2}{*}{80} & \multirow{2}{*}{136} & \multirow{2}{*}{6} & \multirow{2}{*}{Dec, 2009} & ~ \\
~ & ~ & Circuit-I & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{I.} & \multirow{2}{*}{IT-35} & Fundamentals of Computer & \multirow{2}{*}{120} & \multirow{2}{*}{48} & \multirow{2}{*}{105} & \multirow{2}{*}{6} & \multirow{2}{*}{Dec, 2009} & ~ \\
~ & ~ & \& Networking System & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ \hline
I. & IT-37 & Engineering Graphics & 150 & 60 & 121 & 6 & Dec, 2009 & ~ \\ \hline
II. & IT-42 & Mathematics-II & 100 & 40 & 73 & 4 & May, 2010 & ~ \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{II.} & \multirow{2}{*}{IT-7} & Electronic Devices and & \multirow{2}{*}{200} & \multirow{2}{*}{80} & \multirow{2}{*}{148} & \multirow{2}{*}{6} & \multirow{2}{*}{May, 2010} & ~ \\
~ & ~ & Circuit-II & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ \hline
II. & IT-8 & Programming in C++ & 200 & 80 & 178 & 6 & May, 2010 & ~ \\ \hline
II. & IT-9 & Physics & 200 & 80 & 149 & 8 & May, 2010 & ~ \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{II.} & \multirow{2}{*}{IT-10} & Development of Generic & \multirow{2}{*}{100} & \multirow{2}{*}{40} & \multirow{2}{*}{59} & \multirow{2}{*}{3} & \multirow{2}{*}{May, 2010} & ~ \\
~ & ~ & Skill & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ \hline
III. & IT-11 & Digital Electronics & 200 & 80 & 165 & 6 & Dec, 2010 & ~ \\ \hline
III. & IT-12 & System Programming & 175 & 70 & 138 & 6 & Dec, 2010 & ~ \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{III.} & \multirow{2}{*}{IT-13} & Database Management & \multirow{2}{*}{200} & \multirow{2}{*}{80} & \multirow{2}{*}{124} & \multirow{2}{*}{6} & \multirow{2}{*}{Dec, 2010} & ~ \\
~ & ~ & System (DBMS) & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{III.} & \multirow{2}{*}{IT-15} & Elements of Computer & \multirow{2}{*}{175} & \multirow{2}{*}{70} & \multirow{2}{*}{123} & \multirow{2}{*}{6} & \multirow{2}{*}{Dec, 2010} & ~ \\
~ & ~ & Engineering & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ \hline
III. & IT-16 & Software Engineering & 175 & 70 & 132 & 6 & Dec, 2010 & ~ \\ \hline
IV. & IT-17 & Data Structure & 200 & 80 & 168 & 6 & May, 2011 & ~ \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{IV.} & \multirow{2}{*}{IT-18} & Computer Peripheral \& & \multirow{2}{*}{175} & \multirow{2}{*}{70} & \multirow{2}{*}{121} & \multirow{2}{*}{6} & \multirow{2}{*}{May, 2011} & ~ \\
~ & ~ & Devices & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ \hline
IV. & IT-19 & Communication System & 200 & 80 & 103 & 7 & Dec, 2011 & ~ \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{IV.} & \multirow{2}{*}{IT-36} & Fundamentals of Operating & \multirow{2}{*}{175} & \multirow{2}{*}{70} & \multirow{2}{*}{127} & \multirow{2}{*}{6} & \multirow{2}{*}{May, 2011} & ~ \\
~ & ~ & Systems & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ \hline
IV. & IT-21 & Visual Basic & 175 & 70 & 118 & 6 & May, 2011 & ~ \\ \hline
IV. & IT-43 & Open Source Technology & 95 & 38 & 50 & 4 & May, 2011 & ~ \\ \hline
V. & IT-23 & Fiber Optic Communication & 150 & 60 & 112 & 6 & Dec, 2011 & ~ \\ \hline
V. & IT-24 & Network \& Security & 175 & 70 & 117 & 6 & Dec, 2011 & \# \\ \hline
V. & IT-25 & Computer Graphics & 175 & 70 & 130 & 6 & Dec, 2011 & \# \\ \hline
V. & IT-26 & TCP/IP Internet & 120 & 48 & 99 & 6 & Dec, 2011 & \# \\ \hline
V. & IT-38 & Multimedia \& Animation & 200 & 80 & 154 & 7 & Dec, 2011 & ~ \\ \hline
VI. & IT-30 & Project & 200 & 80 & 151 & 9 & May, 2012 & \# \\ \hline
VI. & IT-31 & Web Technology & 150 & 60 & 126 & 6 & May, 2012 & \# \\ \hline
VI. & IT-32 & E-Commerce & 150 & 60 & 113 & 6 & May, 2012 & \# \\ \hline
VI. & IT-34 & Information Technology & 200 & 80 & 156 & 6 & May, 2012 & \# \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{VI.} & \multirow{2}{*}{IT-39} & Object Oriented Modeling & \multirow{2}{*}{200} & \multirow{2}{*}{80} & \multirow{2}{*}{157} & \multirow{2}{*}{6} & \multirow{2}{*}{May, 2012} & \multirow{2}{*}{\#} \\
~ & ~ & \& Design & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
```

How do I make the table align in such a way that there's an equal amount of space on the left as well as on the right?

Comment: When asking questions it is better to provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) both in order to demonstrate what you are trying to do and to help others help you. The MWE should like like `\documentclass...\begin{document}...\end{document}`, it should compile and contain close to the minimal amount of code needed to explain/demonstrate what you are asking. This saves a lot of time for everyone.

Comment: Why not `\begin{center}...\end{center}` ...? The equal amount of space depends on the margin values...

Comment: The main problem with your table is that it's considerably wider than the text block. This is quite independent of the value of `\parindent`. Other than reducing the font size or shrinking the entire table with a command such as `\resizebox`, you might want to look into simplifying the table's contents considerably.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Related: [centering tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/206820)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by using `\resizebox` from the `graphicx` package as follows:

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tabular}{...}
        ...
    \end{tabular}
}
```

The result was as follows:

[image]

Just what I wanted.